# conditional change of script tag based on url routing mvc 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, requirejs

I am using requireJS for my hybrid app . Now I need to change the script tag located into my layout page with conditions on url . The script tag looks something like this

```
<script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Libs/Requirejs/require.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now when the page loads the **`/Home/Login`** the script tag above should be changed to

```
<script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/login")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Libs/Requirejs/require.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Again when I load the page **`/Mail/Index`** The script tag above should change to

```
<script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mail")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Libs/Requirejs/require.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now Note that All of the three pages uses the same `**_Layout.cshtml**` page . And the above script tag is located in `**_Layout.cshtml**` page only .Now how do I track this scripts to change the script tag on change of the Url routing as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd simply use a section for this.  In the layout page:

```
@RenderSection("RequireScripts")
```

And put the script in each page:

```
@section RequireScripts {
    <script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Libs/Requirejs/require.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

---

If you're after a way to avoid re-writing the whole thing (only requiring the relative path), then I suppose you could make use of the dynamic `Page` variable:

```
@if (Page.RequireScript != null)
{
    <script src='~/Scripts/@Page.RequireScript'></script>
}
```

Then the script block would get output to pages that define `RequireScript`.

```
@{
    Page.RequireScript = "Libs/Requirejs/require.min.js";
}
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd soluton seems to be much more elegant . But there are two queries . In `<script src='~/Scripts/@Page.RequireScript'></script>` is `@Page.Requirescript` is a variable or is it an Mvc feature itself ? 2nd is Can i use any variable in that section which might lead to render into `data-main` attribute from the child page ?

Comment: @Joy it's a variable, not a feature of MVC itself.  `Page` is a *dynamic* object, so you can throw whatever properties you want into it.  For your second question, I don't quite understand, would you mind rephrasing?

Comment: Thats alright . I got what I wanted . your answer gave the point which i actually needed :) thanks bro :)